# Magento 2: How to send the email to store owner?

Tags: magento2, email

I have stuck in sending mail to store owner in the below code, but I don't how to programmatically send email to store owner.

Please check my below code and help me solve out.

```
<?php
/**
 * KiwiCommerce
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade to newer versions in the future.
 * If you wish to customize this module for your needs.
 * Please contact us https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/contacts.
 *
 * @category   KiwiCommerce
 * @package    KiwiCommerce_AdminActivity
 * @copyright  Copyright (C) 2018 Kiwi Commerce Ltd (https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/)
 * @license    https://kiwicommerce.co.uk/magento2-extension-license/
 */
namespace KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Cron;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Helper\Data as Helper;
use KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Api\ActivityRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * Class ClearLog
 * @package KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Cron
 */
class ClearLog extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * Default date format
     * @var string
     */
    const DATE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $fileFactory;
    protected $csvProcessor;
    protected $directoryList;

    public $logger;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime
     */
    public $dateTime;
    /**
     * @var \KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Helper\Data
     */
    public $helper;
    /**
     * @var ActivityRepositoryInterface
     */
    public $activityRepository;
    /**
     * @var \KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Api\LoginRepositoryInterface
     */
    public $loginRepository;

    /**
     * ClearLog constructor.
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateTime
     * @param Helper $helper
     * @param ActivityRepositoryInterface $activityRepository
     * @param \KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Api\LoginRepositoryInterface $loginRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $dateTime,
        Helper $helper,
        ActivityRepositoryInterface $activityRepository,
        \KiwiCommerce\AdminActivity\Api\LoginRepositoryInterface $loginRepository
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->helper = $helper;
        $this->activityRepository = $activityRepository;
        $this->loginRepository = $loginRepository;
        $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * Return cron cleanup date
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function __getDate()
    {
        $timestamp = $this->dateTime->gmtTimestamp();
        $day = $this->helper->getConfigValue('CLEAR_LOG_DAYS');
        if ($day) {
            $timestamp -= $day * 24 * 60 * 60;
            return $this->dateTime->gmtDate(self::DATE_FORMAT, $timestamp);
        }
        return null;
    }
    /**
     * Delete record which date is less than the current date
     * @return $this|null
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            if (!$this->helper->isEnable()) {
                return $this;
            }

            if ($date = $this->__getDate()) {

                $activities = $this->activityRepository->getListBeforeDate($date);

                $name = date('m_d_Y_H_i_s');

                $filepath = 'export/Adminactivity/admin_activity_' . $name . '.csv';
                $loginfilepath = 'export/Loginactivity/login_activity_' . $name . '.csv';

                $this->directory->create('export');
                  /* Open file */
                $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');

                $stream->lock();

                $columns = $this->getColumnHeader();

                foreach ($columns as $column) {
                    $header[] = $column;
                }

                /* Write Header */
                $stream->writeCsv($header);

                if (!empty($activities)) {
                    foreach ($activities as $activity) {
                        $activityArray = [];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['entity_id'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['username'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['name'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['admin_id'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['store_id'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['scope'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['action_type'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['remote_ip'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['forwarded_ip'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['user_agent'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['module'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['fullaction'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['item_name'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['item_url'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['is_revertable'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['revert_by'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['created_at'];
                        $activityArray[] = $activity['updated_at'];
                        $stream->writeCsv($activityArray);
                        $activity->delete($activity['entity_id']);
                    }
                }


                //TODO: Remove login activity detail
                if ($this->helper->isLoginEnable()) {

                    $streamLogin = $this->directory->openFile($loginfilepath, 'w+');
                    $streamLogin->lock();
                    $loginColumns = $this->getLoginColumnHeader();

                    foreach ($loginColumns as $columnLog) {
                        $headerLogin[] = $columnLog;
                    }

                    $streamLogin->writeCsv($headerLogin);

                    $loginactivities = $this->loginRepository->getListBeforeDate($date);
                    if (!empty($loginactivities)) {
                        foreach ($loginactivities as $activity) {
                            $loginArray = [];
                            $loginArray[] = $activity['entity_id'];
                            $loginArray[] = $activity['username'];
                            $loginArray[] = $activity['name'];
                            $loginArray[] = $activity['remote_ip'];
                            $loginArray[] = $activity['forwarded_ip'];
                            $loginArray[] = $activity['user_agent'];
                            $loginArray[] = $activity['type'];
                            $loginArray[] = $activity['status'];
                            $loginArray[] = $activity['remarks'];
                            $loginArray[] = $activity['created_at'];

                            $streamLogin->writeCsv($loginArray);
                            $activity->delete($activity['entity_id']);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (\Exception $e) {
           $this->logger->debug($e->getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /* Header Columns */
    public function getColumnHeader() {
        $headers = ['entity_id','username','name','admin_id','store_id','scope','action_type','remote_ip','forwarded_ip','user_agent','module','fullaction','item_name','item_url','is_revertable','revert_by','created_at','updated_at'];
        return $headers;
    }

    /* Header Columns */
    public function getLoginColumnHeader() {
        $headers = ['entity_id','username','name','remote_ip','forwarded_ip','user_agent','type','status','remarks','created_at'];
        return $headers;
    }

}
```

Thanks For Advanced...

Comment: Check this guide: https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the process describe below.

**step 1)**

Create a **email_templates.xml** under **app/code/KiwiCommerce/AdminActivity/etc**

**File: *YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/KiwiCommerce/AdminActivity/etc/email_templates.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="custom_admin_email_template" label="Custom Admin Email" file="custom_adminmail.html" type="html" module="Matrixmedia_CustomeImportmail" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**step 2)**

Create HTML email template file **custom_adminmail.html** under ***app/code/KiwiCommerce/AdminActivity/view/frontend/email/***

**File:** ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/KiwiCommerce/AdminActivity/view/frontend/email/custom_adminmail.html***

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<!--@subject {{trans "Welcome to %store_name" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}} @-->


{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<p>{{trans "welcome you to %store_name. " store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}</p>

<ul>
    <li><strong>{{trans "Info 1:"}}</strong> {{var var_1}}</li>
    <li><strong>{{trans "Info 2:"}}</strong> {{var var_2}}</li>
    <li><strong>{{trans "Info 3:"}}</strong> {{var var_3}}</li>
    <li><strong>{{trans "Info 4:"}}</strong> {{var var_4}}</li>
</ul>


{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

**step 3)**

Update your cron file as below

**File: *YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/KiwiCommerce/Cron/ClearLog.php***

```
<?php

......................
......................
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
......................
......................
......................




 class ClearLog extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

 ......................     
 const XML_PATH_CUSTOM_ADMIN_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'custom_admin_email_template';
 ......................

 public function __construct(         
         ...................... ,
         ...................... ,
         TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
         \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
         ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
         StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,         
         ...................... ,
         ...................... ,

    ) {

        ...................... ,
        ...................... ,
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        ...................... ,
        ...................... ,

    }


    public function execute()
    {

        ......................
        ...................... ,


        try{
             $storeid = 1;
             $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeid); // Chnage Store ID
             $AdminEmailId =  'admin@abc.com'; // Change Admin Email
             $templateId = self::XML_PATH_CUSTOM_ADMIN_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,
             //Set Email Template var
             $templateParams = [
              'store' => $store, 
              'var_1'=>'TEST 1',
              'var_2'=>'TEST 2',
              'var_3'=>'TEST 3',
              'var_3'=>'TEST 4'
             ];
             $isEmailSendSuccess = $this->sendEmailToAdmin(
             $AdminEmailId,
             self::XML_PATH_CUSTOM_IMPORT_EMAIL_TEMPLATE,                                         
             $templateParams
            );

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
              $message = $e->getMessage();                
              $this->logger->info("Error:".$message);       

         }          





    }

private function sendEmailToAdmin($AdminEmail, $templateId,$templateParams = []){                                    
         try{ 
              $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
              $error = false;
              $sender = [
                 'name' =>  $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/name',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE),
                 'email' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email',\Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)
                 ];
               $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
               $transport = $this->transportBuilder
               ->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId) // this code we have mentioned in the email_templates.xml
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                 [
                   'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file
                   'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                  ]
                 )
                 ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
                 ->setFrom($sender)
                 ->addTo($AdminEmail)                
                 ->getTransport();
                 $transport->sendMessage();
                 $this->inlineTranslation->resume();            
                 return true;             
          } catch (\Exception $e) {
              $message = $e->getMessage();
              $this->logger->info("==== Admin Custom  Email Send error=".$message);
              return false;           
          }                     

    }

?>
```